# CSS3 Shapes flickering as they rotate in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm working on a relatively simple 3d shape for a personal project: I haven't constructed anything terribly complicated before, and it's gone pretty smoothly.

The image is supposed to be a milk carton, and everything is fine except the triangular inset pieces on the top. Check out the example to see what I mean:

http://codepen.io/neagle/pen/yuHJg?editors=110

In Chrome, as the carton rotates, you can see the insets flicker in and out of visibility when they should be covered by the rectangles that are in front of them. (In Safari it seems fine.)

I'm using Photon, but if you're concerned that it might be the issue, you can disable it pretty easily and see that the problem is still there.

Anyone have any insight?

Note: Since I'm using a -webkit-mask for the triangles, this example is webkit-only.